# How to hide other data from current user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework, When any user logged in and create a order then he can see his order history, i have created a view to do that task but the current user sees all of the information on the coffee_order table. How can i authenticate from other's data from current user ?

```
class coffeeorderAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = coffee_order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = coffeeorderSerializer
```

I have tried object level authentication in djangorestframework but i am a newbei, i can not do it. please give the solution.

Comment: can you show your coffee_order class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to limit the queryset to the users's coffee orders.

```
class CoffeeOrderAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = CoffeeOrder.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CoffeeOrderSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # I'm not sure what the FK to user is on CoffeeOrder. I assumed customer.
        queryset = queryset.filter(customer=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

I've also changed the classes to be camel cased which is the python standard.